# How do I paginate my list within a scrollview

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, swiftui

I'm attempting to build a social media feed using Swift UI.

Previously I have been using a ForEach loop inside a List, which worked to paginate my posts automatically at the end of the list.

However, now I have elements above the feed that I would like to be scrollable just the same way the post list is.

But it doesn't seem to be paginating my posts at all.

My code is below:

```
ScrollView {
        Text("Home")
        ForEach(postList, id: \.uuid) { post in
                    SinglePostView(post: post)
                        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                        .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                        .id(post)
                }
                .onAppear {
                        
                    if isLoading {
                        return
                    }
                    
                    isLoading = true
                                                    
                    if isLastDoc {
                        isLoading = false
                        return
                    }
                    
                    fetchAllPosts()
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a ScrollView and LazyVStack but I would recommend a List so that you only render what's on screen.

```
struct FeedView: View {
        
        @State var messages: [Int] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
        
        var body: some View {
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                List {
                    ForEach(messages, id: \.hashValue) { message in
                        Text(message.description)
                            .padding()
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                    
                    Color.clear
                        .frame(height: 100)
                        .onAppear {
                            let newList = [8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
                            withAnimation {
                                messages += newList
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[This is a preview](https://github-production-user-asset-6210df.s3.amazonaws.com/52855516/270314764-55dbca08-04d7-4c98-b231-6d9bde2a1899.gif)